# PhysFS_init() returns non-zero with error: "no error"

Tags: c++, windows, physfs

Im experiencing a rather weird crash in my code and im unsure as to what causes it. Im trying to use PhysFS in my c++ code. the code below is part of a class and Visual Studio 2017 tells me that the crash appears in `PHYSFS_mount()` and subsequently in `EnterCriticalSection()`, which to my understanding has something to do with mutexes. Now from my understanding this should be correct (Note that the main calls `initArchives()` first)

```cpp
physfs_initialized = false;

...

void scope::parse_archive(const std::string& archive_path, const std::string& path_in_archive)
{
    assert(physfs_initialized);

    m_archivePath = archive_path;
    m_relativeArchivePath = path_in_archive.substr(1);

    //fsx = std::filesystem or std::expiremental::filesystem whatever floats your boat
    if(exists(fsx::path(archive_path))) return;


    if(!PHYSFS_mount(m_archivePath.c_str(),"",0)) return;
    const auto file = PHYSFS_openRead(m_relativeArchivePath.c_str());

    if(file) m_isValid = true;

    PHYSFS_close(file);
    PHYSFS_unmount(m_archivePath.c_str());
}

...

void initArchives(char ** argv)
{
    if (!PHYSFS_init(argv[0])) physfs_initialized = true;
    //a bit of ugly syntax because of the need to consume the return type
    atexit([]() {PHYSFS_deinit(); });
}
```

The crash apparently appears here

```
int __PHYSFS_platformGrabMutex(void *mutex)
{
    EnterCriticalSection((LPCRITICAL_SECTION) mutex); // <-- here 
    return 1;
} /* __PHYSFS_platformGrabMutex */
```

Am I doing something wrong here ? Is this a problem of the library or even with my OS ? Was there something in the buildstep of PhysFS that I missed ?

Edit: I noticed that I read the return value of PHYSFS_init() wrong, however now I'm even more confused as `PHYSFS_getErrorByCode(PHYSFS_getLastErrorCode())` returns "no error", what is going on here ?

Comment: The project's mailing list has lots of bug reports about this.  Possibly most useful are [this one](http://icculus.org/pipermail/physfs/2018-October/001272.html) and [this one](http://icculus.org/pipermail/physfs/2018-October/001273.html).  Google had no trouble finding them btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in PhysFS regarding Windows 10. That prohibits the correct execution of PHYSFS_init()
changing line  578 of phsyfs_platform_windows.c to

`rc = pGetDir(accessToken, NULL, &psize);`

and a recompile of the library fixed the problem for me :/

https://hg.icculus.org/icculus/physfs/rev/ece6769c0676

https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/resolved-physfs-exception-thrown/25697/11